# looking for a field name that contains specific data (mySql)

Tags: mysql

i got table named "teachers_db" with field names:

```
teacher_name 
instrument1
instrument2 
payment1 
payment2
```

In my program i get list of teachers and what instrument they are teaching.
e.i:

```
Mathew - piano
Mathew - drums
Adam - guitar
```

I want to phrase a code line in mySQL that get a `teacher_name` and `instrument` (instrument1 = "piano" or instrumnet2 = "drums" and so on),  and return the `payment` for it (payment1 if its a piano, playment2 if its a drums).

i'm hammering my head with this problem, please help :)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide an example output and input parameters, if any.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the result is to use two separate queries, combined with a `UNION ALL` operator. For example:

```
 SELECT q.teacher_name
      , q.instrument1 AS instrument
      , q.payment1    AS payment
   FROM teachers_db q
  WHERE q.instrument1 <> ''
  UNION ALL
 SELECT r.teacher_name
      , r.instrument2 AS instrument
      , r.payment2    AS payment
  WHERE r.instrument2 <> ''
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

---

Another approach:

```
SELECT t.teacher_name
     , CASE i.n WHEN 1 THEN t.instrument1 WHEN 2 THEN t.instrument2 END AS instrument
     , CASE i.n WHEN 1 THEN t.payment1    WHEN 2 THEN t.payment2    END AS payment
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2) i
 CROSS
  JOIN teachers_db t
HAVING instrument <> ''
 ORDER BY 1,2
```